# Intellij IDEA ошибка во время развертывания артефакта на Tomcat

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, развертывание

Переехал на новую систему и столкнулся с проблемой развертывания артефакта.
Intellij IDEA 2017.1 Ultimate. При старте на Apache Tomcat 8.5.13 или 9.0.0.M19.
Сообщается о проблеме, и отображается соответственная иконка для "некорректного артефакта", несмотря на его успешный деплой.

Попытка старта.

```
C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\bin\catalina.bat run
[2017-04-06 09:41:15,649] Artifact webapps:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_(1)_webapps"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Programming\Software\SDK\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.116 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.13
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.119 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 27 2017 14:25:04 UTC
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.119 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.13.0
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.119 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.119 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.119 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.120 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Programming\Software\SDK\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.120 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.120 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.120 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_(1)_webapps
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.121 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.122 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_(1)_webapps\conf\logging.properties
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.122 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.122 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.122 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.122 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.123 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.123 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.123 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.123 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.124 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_(1)_webapps
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.124 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.124 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\temp
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.128 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.12 using APR version 1.5.2.
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.129 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
06-Apr-2017 21:41:17.129 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017)
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.482 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.515 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.520 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.524 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.524 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2013 ms
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.575 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.575 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.13
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.596 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.620 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-Apr-2017 21:41:18.627 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 102 ms
Connected to server
[2017-04-06 09:41:18,974] Artifact webapps:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2017-04-06 09:41:19,043] Artifact webapps:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
06-Apr-2017 21:41:28.598 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_(1)_webapps\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
06-Apr-2017 21:41:29.318 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_(1)_webapps\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml has finished in 719 ms
06-Apr-2017 21:41:29.320 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\webapps\docs
06-Apr-2017 21:41:29.360 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\webapps\docs has finished in 39 ms
06-Apr-2017 21:41:29.360 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\webapps\examples
06-Apr-2017 21:41:30.219 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\webapps\examples has finished in 859 ms
06-Apr-2017 21:41:30.220 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\webapps\host-manager
06-Apr-2017 21:41:30.298 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\webapps\host-manager has finished in 78 ms
06-Apr-2017 21:41:30.298 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\webapps\manager
06-Apr-2017 21:41:30.362 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Programming\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\webapps\manager has finished in 63 ms
```

Получаю сообщение:

```
Artifact webapps:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

(Лог-файл пуст)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При повторной попытке задеплоить на лету, получаю:

```
[2017-04-06 10:00:17,325] Artifact webapps:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
06-Apr-2017 22:00:20.896 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context []
[2017-04-06 10:00:21,070] Artifact webapps:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
06-Apr-2017 22:00:30.947 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_(1)_webapps\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
06-Apr-2017 22:00:31.025 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_(1)_webapps\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml has finished in 77 ms
```

Но сам артефакт развернут успешно, если я вручную пропишу адрес в браузере или нажму на кнопку "Refresh deploy status" то на консоль будет выведено сообщение:

```
[2017-04-06 10:04:09,633] Artifact webapps:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
```

И индикатор будет отображаться корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другие сервера работают на лету, почему у меня не получается тоже самое с Tomcat ?

Comment: это не ответ на вопрос, но так как вы делаете - делать не стоит.

Comment: Как не стоит делать, это ведь стандартные действия, разве нет?

Comment: не стоит разворачивать приложение таким образом. зачем вы его разворачиваете локально? для какой цели?

Comment: Хочу посмотреть на его внешний вид/работоспособность, а вообще я только учусь делать веб-приложения. Да и раньше эта функция в idea работала как нужно. Вообще по ощущениям, как будто бы idea отображает данные о состоянии деплоя еще до окончания запуска сервера.

Comment: попробуйте развернуть самостоятельно, без помощи IDEA.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, вручную все проходит гладко, с другими ide так же, но интересует в чем же все-таки дело с IDEA, это ведь не нормальное поведение? Вообще раньше система стояла на hdd, сейчас на ssd(может в этом дело). Я даже попробовал перенести все инструменты на старый диск (sdk,ide,tomcat).

Comment: я бы порекомендовал обратиться в службу поддержки. Там скорей всего помогут быстрее.